# Cannot change django auth urls namespace

Tags: django, authentication, django-urls, django-authentication

I'm including all Django auth urls in one go, like this:

```
app_name = "main"
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    ...
]
```

However, if I go to `/accounts/password_reset/` and add my email, the email gets sent but it can't resolve the "reset done" url. Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password_reset/

Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I assume the reason is that it is resolvable at "main:password_reset_done". Then I add a namespace in my url include like this:

```
app_name = "main"
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls", namespace="main")),
    ...
]
```

But then I get another error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
```

Which doesn't make sense, as I already have `app_name` set.

Comment: Try removing `app_name = "main"`?

Comment: try other than main

Comment: Are you adding it to the main `urls.py` (i.e. the one specified in `settings.ROOT_URLCONF`)?

Comment: Tried removing it, no difference. Tried other than main, no difference. No, I'm adding it into one that is being included by settings.ROOT_URLCONF. I tried adding another app_name there but still, no difference, same error message as on all occasions.